# JPA findAll(spec,Sort)

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I have this code to get all transaction between 2 dates. I would like to get a desc sorted list. What are the possibilities?

```
@Override
public List<Transaction> searchBySubmitDate(final Date startDate, 
                                            final Date endDate) {
    return transactionRepository.findAll(new Specification<Transaction>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Transaction> transaction, 
                                     CriteriaQuery<?> q, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            Predicate between = cb.between(transaction.get(Transaction_.dateSubmit), startDate, endDate);

            return between;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@Override
    public List<Transaction> searchBySubmitDate(final Date startDate, 
                                                final Date endDate) {
        return transactionRepository.findAll(new Specification<Transaction>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Transaction> transaction, 
                                         CriteriaQuery<?> q, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                Predicate between = cb.between(transaction.get(Transaction_.dateSubmit), startDate, endDate);

                return between;
            }
        },new Sort(Direction.DESC,"dateSubmit"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The repository has [another method taking a Sort as additional argument](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html#findAll%28org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification,%20org.springframework.data.domain.Sort%29). Call this method with an appropriate Sort instance.

Comment: I tried that it doesnt work, i might use it in a wrong way. List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("dateSubmit");
  Sort sort= new Sort(Direction.DESC, list);

Comment: what SQL query does it generate?

Answer (score -2):

I thought I would leave a more up-to-date answer, since it's been 7 years. This is how we do it now:

```
interface TransactionRepository extends Repository<Transaction, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Transaction AS t " +
        "WHERE t.date >= :since AND t.date <= :until", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Transaction> findTransactionBetween(@Param("since" String since, 
                                                    @Param("until" String until);
}
```

You can read more in the [Spring JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)