# Spring MVC pagination using Spring Data and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need to paginate table which displays filtered data from one DB table. For example, I have a CARS table, and I need to paginate only `... WHERE CAR = "BMW"`. So far, I used JPA `repository.findAll(Pageable pageable)` method, if I paged data from one table only.

Is there any standard way to achieve this using standard repository methods, or do I have to write my own implementation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to:

```
Page<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

I think this is what you are looking for. `Specification<T>`, is basically an object to specify a WHERE clause which will filter your query.

Javadoc [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAll%28org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification,%20org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable%29).

An example (without `Pageable`) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8637571/787375).

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own method in your `Repository` interface. In any method you can pass a `Pageable` parameter.

```
Page<Car> findByCar(String car, Pageable pageable);
```

This saves you from having to create a `Specification`-based query.